# VBA Countiff error

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a snippet of code in my VBA excel macro that is counting the number of times a specific row appears, then adding that number to the corresponding employee pin on a different sheet.  Here is the code:

```
    For d = 2 To table3.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        saP = table3.Cells(d, 1).Value
        If table3.Cells(d, 5).Value > 3 Then
            numVils = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(table4.Range("$A:$A"), saP, table4.Range("$D:$D"), "015D", table4.Range("$G:$G"), "0/1" Or "0/2")
            table3.Cells(d, 5).Value = table3.Cells(d, 5).Value + numVils
            table3.Cells(d, 4).Value = table3.Cells(d, 4).Value + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(table4.Range("$A:$A"), saP, table4.Range("$D:$D"), "015D")
        Else
            table3.Cells(d, 5).Value = table3.Cells(d, 5).Value + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(table4.Range("$A:$A"), saP, table4.Range("$D:$D"), "015D")
        End If
    Next
```

For some reason it works for the first two times I run it, then gets an error on the third.  Coinicdentally, the third run is when many table3.cells(d,5).value > 3.  It is getting an error on the fourth line.  Are there any errors in my code that is causing this to happen?

Comment: Did you try to compile the code and see where exactly the code gives an error?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that catches my eye is the 'or' in the 4th line.

I don't believe you can have this. Probably need something like:

```
numVils = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(table4.Range("$A:$A"), saP, table4.Range("$D:$D"), "015D", table4.Range("$G:$G"), "0/1") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(table4.Range("$A:$A"), saP, table4.Range("$D:$D"), "015D", table4.Range("$G:$G"), "0/2")
```